# PHP not showing exact image path stored in database

Tags: image, path

{"result":[{"Image_path":"http://192.168.10.6//Login/Insert_Cat/cat_image/Seq_1.JPG"}]}
This is out put of my php code..i am not getting right path like //.. please help

$row["img_path"]));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>

Comment: Is the double slash stored in the database? It could be added before insert as a means of security, or on JSON encode. Try looking at `var_dump($result)` to see if it is still added in.

Comment: when using JSON encode it gives in out put as {"result":[{"Image_path":"http:\/\/192.168.10.6\/\/Login\/Insert_Cat\/cat_image\/Seq_1.JPG"}]} how ca I have the exact path retrieved